# How to make the period of VWAP 2-day long?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I used macOS's Calendar app to make an illustration about my goal. Also created the wanted result manually on the second image.

You see that there's a normal VWAP, reset everyday. I would like to **make VWAP's period 2 days long but always anchored to the previous day**. Practically, it would be an automatic Anchored VWAP that is started at yesterday 0:00, *see magenta curve*.

(Additional goal is the same with 3-day long period, anchored to 0:00 of the day before yesterday, *see purple curve*.)

VWAP Bands for these secondary VWAP curves are not needed.

What's the trick? I couldn't manage to find it out myself.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Please show what you tried or reproduce the unexpected behavior you are asking about.

Comment: Although I have indicators made of 1000+ codelines, and even if I know I should use a logical system of Boolean variables, I am clueless so I have no code. There's the source code of the original and basic VWAP indicator, obviously that should be extended with this Boolean logic to make the period more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

We need to count the `isNewPeriod` Boolean variable's `true` occurrences then use a modulo for two additional period markers, adding it to the basic VWAP indicator's code, after its `isNewPeriod` switch definition line:

```
var int PeriodCounter = 0
if isNewPeriod
    PeriodCounter += 1

isNewDouble1Period = switch anchor
    "Session"   => isNewPeriod and (PeriodCounter % 2)) 
    => false

isNewDouble2Period = switch anchor
    "Session"   => isNewPeriod and not(PeriodCounter % 2))
    => false
```

Then use it for the calculation function calls as period marker Boolean variables.